# Preventing images from loading from script

Tags: javascript, html, noscript

I've got a slight problem with some image tags. We have a service (legacy) that returns a bunch of HTML. The image tags here contain relative paths in their HTML, which is relative to the wrong base. It's simple enough for me to fix this up- just bung it in a div, select the images, and fiddle their URL.

The problem is that as soon as you put that HTML in the div, the browser requests the incorrect URL. So the console jams up with 404 warnings for the images, even though the whole point of putting them in the div is to correct the problem.

I've seen that you can prevent the image from loading with a noscript tag. Unfortunately, when replacing the div with a noscript, we've had a fairly big problem- it seems that manipulating noscript tags from script is, well, very difficult. The native functions (in Chrome) seem to return completely different results. For example, when we try to set the inner HTML of the noscript, it seems to think that we actually meant to set that HTML as the text.

How can I prevent the image tags from loading their URLs until after I have fixed them up?

Edit: I have the HTML back as a string from an AJAX request.

Comment: How are you putting that HTML in the div? Dynamic HTML generation on the serverside? AJAX then JS insertion? In both cases, what prevents you from manipulating the HTML before it is inserted?

Comment: @Shilly I don't think that's right - I've seen browsers trigger loads simply by creating an `Image` object and setting its `src` property without adding anything to the DOM.  Indeed that's the entire premise behind most "image pre-load" scripts.

Comment: Oh, just tested it in the console and you're right. creating and image tag and using setAttribute to change the src will autodownload the src, I didnt' knwo that yet, thanks! I'll remove my reply. Edit: guess a workaround is downloading the html as text/plain and manipulating the string.

Comment: @Amadan: Nothing. The problem is that you don't need to insert it to trigger the 404, as soon as it's any kind of element you get the 404. And manipulating HTML as a raw string is not particularly simple to do.

Comment: I could do, but are you seriously suggesting that I implement an HTML parser in JavaScript?

Comment: @Puppy please clarify your question , 404 not found for resources are usually logged in your console , unless you have other issues.

Comment: @Puppy Could you share with us which way you choosed, if any, to solve this issue?

Comment: @ProllyGeek: Yes, they are. That's the whole problem that this question is about.

Comment: @LGSon: I have not solved this issue.

Comment: Maybe if you post an update how the returned html string looks like, I might be able to figure a way to help?

Answer (score 0):

This might/might not solve your particluar issue as I don't have any code to evaluate. This methods have been tested successfully (no console errors) on Chrome/Edge/FF.

Based on your edit where AJAX is used, adding a html string using script:

```
var el = document.createElement("DIV");
el.innerHTML = '<img src="wrong_path.jpg" />';
var imgs = el.getElementsByTagName("IMG");
imgs[0].src = "http://placehold.it/350x150";
document.body.appendChild(el);
```

Another way that might could solve it could be a DOM parser, to convert a string to HTML, iterate the images and update their "src" and return a subset of the DOM to be inserted into the existing DOM.

Src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser

If one need to catch an insert to manually inspect the element inserted, DOM node inserts could be used:

Src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18152595/2827823

```
document.body.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function (evt) {
    if (evt.target.tagName == "IMG") {        
        evt.target.src = "http://placehold.it/350x150";
    }
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<img id="foo" src="wrong_path_bar.png"/>';
```

If one need to catch *these generated errors* without manually look for them, an error event handler could be used:

Src: [Alter the prototype of an image tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151999/alter-the-prototype-of-an-image-tag)

```
window.addEventListener("error", function(e) {
    if ( e && e.target && e.target.nodeName && e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "img" ) {
        // Bad image src
        // e.target.src = "Do an url replacement";
    }
}, true);
```